# Parsing java long value to String in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin, long-integer

I have a Java class that is generate by ApolloClient framework.
In generally , all of my code is written in Kotlin.
There is a problem that long value in Java can not parsed to String( or Long) in Kotlin.

Here is the snippet code:
(Java code)
CountryCode.java

```
public class CountryCode {
    private long code;

    public long getCode(){
      return code;
    }
}
```

(Kotlin code)
CountryUseCase.kt

```
fun getCode(countryCode: CountryCode) : String {
    return countryCode.getCode()   // We have to convert long to String here !!!
}
```

How to convert long value of Java class to String in Kotlin class ?

Comment: `countryCode.getCode().toString()`

Comment: @yole : There none of public method allow you pars long value to string in Kotlin. 
Basically, Kotlin does not have long value. Only Long

Comment: Before telling me that my solution does not work, could you please try it first?

Comment: Thank you! Let me try it

Comment: @yole Thank you man ! It works . Kotlin auto cast long to Long so we can convert to String by toString()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`kotlin.Long`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-long/index.html) type

> Represents a 64-bit signed integer. On the JVM, non-nullable values of this type are represented as values of the primitive type `long`.

While `Long?` would be represented as `java.lang.Long`.

You'll find a `toString()` method within the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-long/to-string.html) as well.